# How can I change member variable when it's passed as an argument to a method?

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to use the `unitConverter` method below to change the values of `u1_1SCost` and `u1_1MCost` in my `GameController` class:

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
     public float u1_1SCost, u1_1MCost;

     public GameController data;

     public void unitConverter(float SCost, float MCost)
     {
         if (SCost >= 60)
         {
            MCost += Mathf.Floor(SCost / 60); SCost = SCost % 60; 
            Debug.Log(GameController.data.u1_1MCost);
         }
     }
 }
```

I call `unitConverter` from another script:

```
public class anotherScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        GameController.data.unitConverter(GameController.data.u1_1SCost, GameController.data.u1_1MCost);
    }
}
```

---

At `SCost = 60`, `Debug.Log(GameController.data.u1_1MCost)` still showed 0.

However `Debug.Log(MCost)` showed 1.

How can I change `u1_1MCost`? Doesn't it change by changing `MCost`?

Answer (score 1):

In C#, numeric types like `float` or `int` are what are called **Value Types**, in contrast to eg. classes which are **Reference Types**.

When you assign a value type to a variable or pass it as an argument to a method, you're assigning / passing its *value*, not a reference to the original. So for example:

```
float a = 1;
Debug.Log(a);    // Prints 1
float b = a;     // Copies the current value of a into b
b = 2;           // Sets the value of b, does nothing to a
Debug.Log(a);    // Prints 1 - a is still unchanged
Debug.Log(b);    // Prints 2 - only b got the new value
```

Compare this to a reference type like an array:

```
float[] a = new float[] {1};
Debug.Log(a[0]); // Prints 1
float[] b = a;   // Puts a reference to the same array into b
b[0] = 2;        // Changes the first element of the shared array
Debug.Log(a[0]); // Prints 2 this time!
Debug.Log(b[0]); // Also prints 2 - they're the same array, just two references to it
```

The same goes when passing a variable as an argument to a method. If it's a value type, it gets passed by value by default - the method gets a local copy of the value, and changing it won't change the original.

But, as you found, we can override this default behaviour using the `ref` keyword, which says "pass this by reference, even though you'd normally just copy the value":

```
void MakeTheValueTwo(float a) {
  a = 2;
}

void MakeTheReferenceTwo(ref float a) {
  a = 2;
}

void Test() {
  float a = 1;
  Debug.Log(a); // Prints 1

  MakeTheValueTwo(a);
  Debug.Log(a); // Still prints 1 - the method modified its local copy of a, not the original.

  MakeTheReferenceTwo(ref a);
  Debug.Log(a); // Prints 2 - the method modified the original a, since it had a reference to it.
}
```

So, if you want a method to modify the source variables passed to it as arguments, mark them with `ref` in both the method's declaration and its call site (requiring the keyword in both places ensures that this change from the default behaviour is clearly visible to readers of the code and not unexpected).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with c# "ref" keyword

Comment: What's your "final" code? Where did you add `ref`?